# MEF instantiation of an export part

Tags: c#, mef, spring.net

**First, the simple question.**

Is it possible to receive an `event` when MEF (System.ComponentModel.Composition) creates an instance of a part?
When this occurs I want to reflect over the created object and wire up various attributes.  In Spring.Net this is possible with the `IObjectPostProcessor` interface.

The background is that I trying to implement Publisher/Subscriber pattern in MEF.   Basically the subscriber class does this:

```
class MyContoller
{
   [Command("Print")]
   public void Print() { ... }

   [Command("PrintPreview")]
   public void PrintPreview() { ... }
}
```

And I want to detect when MyController is instantiated and wire up **any methods** that have the `CommandAttribute`.

A publisher, such as a menu item, would do `Command.Get("Print").Fire()` to publish the aforementioned event.

**Second Question**

Maybe there is an alternative pattern in MEF that I am missing!!!

I've seen some postings about [MEF, Prism and the Event Aggregate](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2009/02/23/event-aggregation-with-mef-with-and-without-eventaggregator/), but it appears fairly complex.

**FYI**

Just for reference, here's the original for Spring.Net implementation:

```
class CommandAttributeProcessor : IObjectPostProcessor
{
  static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CommandAttributeProcessor));

  public object PostProcessAfterInitialization(object instance, string objectName)
  {
     foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in instance.GetType().GetMethods())
     {
        foreach (CommandAttribute attr in methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandAttribute), true))
        {
           if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
              log.Debug(String.Format("Binding method '{0}.{1}' to command '{2}'.", instance.GetType().Name, methodInfo.Name, attr.CommandName));

           Command command = Command.Get(attr.CommandName);
           command.Execute += (EventHandler) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler), instance, methodInfo);
        }
     }
     return instance;
  }

  public object PostProcessBeforeInitialization(object instance, string name)
  {
     return instance;
  }
```

}

Comment: I've just seen http://hammett.castleproject.org/index.php/2009/02/mef-exporting-and-importing-methods/  Perhaps this is the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InterceptingCatalog from MEF Contrib ([MEF Contrib on codeplex](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/) or you can install it by nuGet) and implement IExportedValueInterceptor interface to wire up methods that have CommandAttribute:

```
//using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
//using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
//using MefContrib.Hosting.Interception;
//using MefContrib.Hosting.Interception.Configuration;

public class CommandAttributeProcessor : IExportedValueInterceptor
{
    public object Intercept(object value)
    {
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in value.GetType().GetMethods())
        {
            foreach (CommandAttribute attr in methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandAttribute), true))
            {
                // do something with command attribute
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

and at creating MEF catalog, you need to add interception configuration with your interceptor (CommandAttributeProcessor) and wrap your catalog in InterceptingCatalog like this:

```
InterceptionConfiguration interceptionConfiguration = new InterceptionConfiguration();
interceptionConfiguration.AddInterceptor(new CommandAttributeProcessor());
InterceptingCatalog interceptingCatalog = new InterceptingCatalog(assemblyCatalog, interceptionConfiguration);
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(interceptingCatalog);
```

Answer (score 3):

This may not help, but the part itself can receive notification when it is fully composed:

[Automatically call method after part has been composed in MEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615687/automatically-call-method-after-part-has-been-composed-in-mef)

Also, you probably already know this (and it might not really be related to what you are trying to do), but you can decorate your Exports and Imports such the concrete implementations are named.  So, you could have an exported class something like this:

```
[Export("Print", typeof(IPlugin))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
class Print : IPlugin
{
  .
  .
  .
  public Fire()
  {
    //Do something;
  }
}


class PrintMenuItem
{
  IPlugin _plugin;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  PrintMenuItem([Import("Print", typeof(IPlugin)] plugin)
  {
    _plugin = plugin;
  }

  void Execute()
  {
    _plugin.Fire();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for THE quick response, I've given you a +1.  However, my subscriber class (the controller) does a lot more that just printing.  I need some pattern to allow **multiple** subscriber methods to be invoked.